# Merge $var positions in a loop with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, loops

I have this PHP that is helping me populate a script:

```
<script>
(function($){

    <?php foreach($buttons as $button) { // loop throught all available buttons ?>

    // by clicking button one
    $('.button-1').click( function () { 
        // display:none to all filters but filter-1
        $('.filter-2, .filter-3, .filter-4, .filter-5, .filter-6').css({display: "none"});
        // guarantee filter-1 will be visible with display: block;
        $('.filter-1').css({display: "block"});
    });        
            
    <?php } ?>

})(jQuery);
</script>
```

But the numbers of buttons and filters (button-1, filter-2, and etc) are currently manually set, and I don't know how to build the logic, where

- First iteration? Set 'button-1', set `display:hide` to all filters but 'filter-1' and `display:block` only to 'filter-1'
- Second iteration? Set 'button-2', set `display:hide` to all filters but 'filter-2' and `display:block` only to 'filter-2'
- And so on until foreach is over

How can I build this logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do it in a loop. Give all the buttons a common class `button`, and add a handler to all of them. This can then get the specific button number from an attribute, and use that in the code to determine which filter to display.

So the HTML for the buttons will be something like this:

```
<button class="button" data-filter="1">Filter 1</button>
<button class="button" data-filter="2">Filter 2</button>
and so on
```

and the HTML for the filters will be:

```
<div class="filter-1 filter">blah</div>
<div class="filter-2 filter">lorum ipsum</div>
and so on
```

Then your jQuery code will simply be

```
$(".button").click(function() {
  let filternum = $(this).data("filter");
  $(".filter").hide();
  $(`.filter-${filternum}`).show();
}
```

This adds the handler to all the buttons at once.